# What exactly is the "$\mathbb{R}$" in $L(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: notation, set-theory, descriptive-set-theory

In $L(\mathbb{R})$, presumably $L_0(\mathbb{R})$ is the transitive closure of "$\mathbb{R}$", but what exactly is meant by "$\mathbb{R}$"? (i.e. which set theoretic representation of “the reals” is $\mathbb{R}$ intended to denote in this context?)

My default guess would be that "$\mathbb{R}$" means $\mathcal{P}(\omega)$ (the *universe's* power set of $\omega$), in which case $L_0(\mathbb{R}) = \mathcal{P}(\omega)$. But I could imagine other representations of "$\mathbb{R}$":

- With rational numbers represented as pairs of finite ordinals, the elements of "$\mathbb{R}$" could be sets of such rationals (i.e. literal Dedekind cuts)
- This [article](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/large-cardinals-determinacy/#BasNot) talks about "$\mathbb{R}$" meaning $\omega^{\omega}$ (which doesn't really make sense to me, but there it is...)
- In set theory with "atoms" (a.k.a. "urelements"), I suppose "$\mathbb{R}$" could be a set of atoms.

I suppose in principle there might be multiple valid choices, but is there an established convention for what "$\mathbb{R}$" is usually understood to mean for $L(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: See Yiannis Moschovakis, [Descriptive set theory (American Mathematical Society, 2nd en .2009)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Descriptive_Set_Theory/w0GZAwAAQBAJ), page 9: "Let $\omega = \{ 0, 1, 2, . . . \}$ be the set of (nonnegative) *integers* and let $\mathbb R$ be the set of *real numbers*."

Comment: In what context did you see the expression $L(\mathbb R)$?

Comment: We have a *theory of real numbers*, either axiomatic or "constructed" that defines what reals are: in the second approach, reals can be defined as Dedekind cuts, sequences of rationals. Then there are theories "using" them, like calculus that assumes the existence of reals (with usual properties) to approach new mathematical objects: functions, spaces, based on them.

Comment: So, what is *Descriptive ST*? Moschovakis, page 9: "The main business of *Descriptive Set Theory* is the study of $\omega, \mathbb R$ and their subsets, with particular emphasis on the definable sets of integers and reals."

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA : That passage from Moschovakis’ book does not (as far as I can tell) specify *which* set-theoretic representation of the real numbers is intended by the symbol $\mathbb{R}$ when speaking of $L(\mathbb{R})$ (see my question for hypothesized possible set-theoretic representations of the real numbers)

Comment: Exactly; IMO, this is not relevant for the theory, that assumes the existence of "usual" natural and real numbers.

Comment: @littleO : The model $L(\mathbb{R})$ is discussed (somewhat) in chap. 13 (e.g. definition 13.24) of Jech *Set Theory* (3rd edition), and also in this Wikipedia [article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/L(R))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The point is that it doesn't *really* matter. Of course, if you chose that $\Bbb R$ is represented by a set of functions which are injections from $\mathcal P(\omega)$ into the ordinals, then formally speaking $L(\Bbb R)$ will include well-orderings of $\mathcal P(\omega)$. **Clearly**, this is not what we mean to investigate.

Taking either $\mathcal P(\omega)$, or $2^\omega$ or $\omega^\omega$, or even a subset of $\mathcal P(\omega)$ which is order-isomorphic to the reals, or any "reasonable variation thereof" will result in the same model. Why? Because we can translate one structure to the other in a very definable way. So whichever coding you take for the real numbers, as long as it is reasonable, will include all of the above.

For sake of concreteness, we will often think about $\mathcal P(\omega)$ as representing the real numbers. It is usually easy enough, since it's already a transitive set, to simply build the rest of the $L$-hierarchy on top of that.